# Making sure associated column is unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Issue:** I want to make sure a column is unique and if an update/create occurs, it doesn't create a new row but will just edit the existing row.

More focused issue: I have a stripe account table which was previously associated to a User with the following code:

**stripe_account.rb (model)**

```
  belongs_to :user, optional: true

  has_one :bank_account

  validates :user_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

This worked.

**Although,** i recently added a new devise model, Affiliates, which is its own model and table and "has_many :users".. it will be used for having affiliate accounts attached to Users so when a user sells a product, they receive an affiliate commission via stripe.

Now, I ran into an issue while testing out creating a stripe account for an affiliate (same issue will happen with users now).

**I have this model:**

```
belongs_to :user, optional: true

  belongs_to :affiliate, optional: true

  has_one :bank_account

  validates :user_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  validates :affiliate_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

The issue is, the "validates" - if im signed in with current_affiliate, i need to comment out user_id for it to work, vice versa.

When I take them away completely, the table creates a new row.  Now it does erase the "affiliate_id" or "user_id" param in the stripe_account table, but it keeps the row which means it creates a new stripe_account ID - and this is inconvenient.  I need it to simply overwrite the current ID (row) the user is already associated with like how it was working before i added a new Devise model.

How can I make it so the edit/update simply overwrites the current row already associated with the signed in user or affiliate id without creating a new row?

Comment: I think you need to handle this yourself as Rails cannot do it.

Comment: In your association definitions, why do you specify that they're optional, only to validate their presence via validations? Rails 5 validates presence of a `belongs_to` association by default.
Also, sorry if this is silly, I am not a native English speaker, but if affiliate accounts can be attached to users, doesn't this mean that a user can have many affiliates, instead of the other way around?

Comment: @emaillenin what do you mean exactly? It was working before i added the affiliate devise model.  theres no way to validate depending on whos signed in?

Comment: @StefanRendevski  Yeah i think you're right.  I want Users to have 1 affiliate but affiliates can be assigned to many users... I currently have the models set up like this: (in affiliate.rb model) = has_many :users ... (in users.rb model) belongs_to :affiliate .... Is this not right?

Comment: --- and then i have affiliate_id in the users table

Comment: You need to rethink it. If an affiliate can be assigned to many users it sounds like you need a join table. Otherwise you can only ever assign a single user.

Comment: Can you explain? If a User has the affiliate_id, the affiliate can be assigned to any user.  Is the way i did it not right?

Comment: How i want it to work:for example... Affiliate ID 1 can be assigned to User ID 1, 2, ,3 ,etc.   --- I have an affiliate_id in the Users table.... i already tested it and it works for making the payments but is the way i set the models up not correct?  ---and to clarify further, having a new row in the stripe_account table doesn't effect anything aside from a new row being created.  I'm just looking for a way to override the account instead of creating a new one... but  i was also thinking it may be good to keep the data also.

Comment: Ok I was just thinking.  I currently have this: User model "belongs_to :affiliate, optional: true" and then in Affiliate model "has_many :users" --- should be it, User Model: "has_one :affiliate" and then in Affiliate Model "belongs_to :user, optional: true" (optional, so they can create and account without errors)...  The User model has an affiliate_id in the table, but affiliate model has no user_id.  Is that right, or which one is, or am i wrong on both?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it when updating the record. Validations are there to ensure that it is not allowed to have several StripeAccount with the same user, but you have to make it happen. So, for updating a record or create a new one if it doesn't exist you can use [`find_or_create_by`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by) and look by `user` or `user_id`, something like (I don't know exactly the fields you want to update):

```
StripeAccount.find_or_create_by(user: user) do |stripe_account|
  stripe_account.bank = bank
  stripe_account.money = 20
end
```

BTW, in your validation, you may want to validate the presence of `user` instead of `user_id`, as this would ensure not only that the field `user_id` is set, but also that there is a User with that id:

```
validates :user, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

Comment: if you want to find the stripe account when logged in as an affiliate, you'll need `StripeAccount.where(user: user).or(StripeAccount.where(affiliate: affiliate))`, and if it does not exist, then you create it.

Comment: @Ana Maria, I think this may be the right way.  because in the stripeaccount controller in the update method i hav something like "begin @.stripe_account = StripeAccount.new(stripe_account_params)"   --- but i put thought into this and it may be best for me to actually keep the data for my records - at least for maybe like 90 days or something